# 私に言われても versus 私が言われても

Tags: grammar, particle-に, passive-voice, ambiguity

I am aware that "言われる" means "to be told". My impression would be that "私に言われても" means "Even if I told you..." while "私が言われても" means "Even if I am told...".

But [this site answer](http://eikaiwa-phrase.com/2802.html) seems to suggest that another interpretation of "私に言われても" is "Even if I am told..."

Is that a correct interpretation, and, if possible to explain, why?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14361/9831

Answer (score 12, accepted):

私**に**言われても is Suffering Passive (迷惑の受身), a kind of Indirect Passive Structure (間接受身構文), and 私**が**言われても is Direct Passive Structure (直接受身構文).

「（あなたが）私に言う」 (Active/能動) "You tell me."
→ Direct Passive: 「私が（あなたに）言われる」  "I am told (by you)."
→ Indirect Passive: 「（私が）（あなたに）私に*言われる」  "You tell me (and it affects me in some way)." This means "You do the action 私**に**言う (you tell me) and it affects me or I am suffered/annoyed, etc." <sub>*The に marks the indirect object of 言う.</sub>

So... yes, that is a correct interpretation, and 「私**に**言われても（困る）...」 is actually far more natural and more common than 「私**が**言われても...」 for saying "Even if I'm told / Even if you tell me (I can't do anything)..."

For more about Indirect Passive, you could refer to:

- [How to interpret indirect passives?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15933/9831)
- [直接受身・間接受身・持ち主の受身の文法](http://www.tomojuku.com/blog/passive/passive-4/)
- [Wikipedia 間接受身ー迷惑の受身](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%97%E5%8B%95%E6%85%8B#.E9.96.93.E6.8E.A5.E5.8F.97.E8.BA.AB)

Comment: I know this answer is a few years old, but I just came across it as I was curious about this structure. I skimmed through the Japanese links you gave and didn't see any examples like 私に言われても where the person who is suffering uses "に", but maybe I missed something. Can you provide other examples of this in modern Japanese?

Comment: @Locksleyu 「私に聞かれても(困る)」ってよく使われますね。「うちに来られても(困る)」とか。 `私に言われても where the person who is suffering uses "に"` <- The に marks the goal of the verb 言う, 聞く, 来る. It's 私に/うちに in 私**に**言う say **to** me, うち**に**来る come **to** my place.