# Why is に used with this verb?

Tags: translation, particle-に, passive-voice

I just read a manga where by context a girl broke up with her boyfriend. She says this.

> 逃げられたの 彼氏に！！
>
> 仕事に入れ込みすぎだって

Why is 彼氏に used alongside the verb?

Comment: Related, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/55624/9831

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 逃げられたの 彼氏に！！

As you've noticed, this is an inverted word order of:

> 彼氏に逃げられたの

逃げられた here is Suffering Passive (迷惑の受身), which is a kind of Indirect Passive (間接受身).
As you know, in passive sentences the agent (動作主) of the action is marked with に. eg お母さんが私を褒める → 私がお母さん**に**褒められる. Here the agent of 逃げる is 彼氏, hence:

彼氏が逃げた (active) *My boyfriend ran away.*
→ 彼氏**に**逃げられた (indirect passive) *My boyfriend ran away from me (which affected me in some way). / My boyfriend up and left (on me).*

For more on Suffering Passive / Indirect Passive:

- [How to interpret indirect passives?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15933/9831)
- [私に言われても versus 私が言われても](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54800/9831)

Comment: Thanks. On another question. Does "仕事に入れ込みすぎだって" mean "I got too engrossed in my work" or something along the lines of "After all we've been through together"?

Comment: These two lines are said by one person? If so, 「『仕事に入れ込み過ぎだ』って。」 "He said 'You're too engrossed/immersed in your work'." The 「って。」 means "He said..." ≂「って言っ(てい)た。」. I think she's saying "My boyfriend left me, saying that I'm too devoted to work (to care about him)." 彼女が彼氏より仕事を優先するので、彼氏が「仕事をがんばりすぎだ」って文句を言って別れた、っていう文脈ですかね・・