# When are good situations to use the phrase "見事にやられた"?

Tags: phrases, set-phrases

When are good situations to use the phrase "見事にやられた" ?

In the language guide book "Shadowing," the authors use it to refer to doing very badly on an exam.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You say "やられた!" when you acknowledge that you have been outsmarted, outperformed or outdone by someone. For example, when you lose a game or find yourself outmaneuvered by your opponent, you can say "やられた!" to admit defeat. Other situations in which you might say "やられた!" include when a competitor releases a new product that outperforms yours, when your rival solves a problem that you were struggling with, or when you're surprised by a prank. Adding 見事に ("excellently; neatly") as an intensifier emphasizes the extent of your defeat or surprise.

When you say "(見事に)やられた" after getting a bad score on a test, it implies something like "The teacher outsmarted/tricked me and gave me unexpected (yet reasonable) questions!"

**EDIT:** Grammatically, やられた is the (past) passive form of やる ("to do"), and this type of passive is called ["suffering passive"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/70533/5010) (迷惑の受け身). The idea is someone did something and it negatively affected you.

Comment: In English, we may say informally that one "got played", which seems to me to capture the nuance pretty well. Although it wouldn't make sense in the context of taking an exam.