# What's the function of に here in this sentence with a passive verb?

Tags: translation

I just stumbled on this sentence.

> 君にあそこまで言われたらいいよ

From what I've learned 言われたら is passive. So it's "When I'm told..."?

I'm confused whether this sentence means "When you tell me that much, it's fine. " or "when i tell you that much is fine?

Does に here mean 君 is the one doing the 言う？ or is he doing the one the action is being directed to?

Sorry if my question sounds confusing

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14362/16104 related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This に is rather simply marking the action taker in a passive sentence. In other words, this 君に is "**by** you" or "**from** you", not "**to** you".

But the role of に in a passive sentence depends on the context, as shown in the link by Felipe Oliveira. Usually it's not necessary to say 僕に in a passive sentence when the implied subject is also 僕 ("I was told something to me" is redundant also in English). However, if you want to emphasize "to me" for some reason, saying 僕に in the sense of "to me" is possible. Compare:

> 彼女に「すごい」と言われた。
> I was told "Great" by her. / She said "Great" to me.
>
> 僕に「すごい」と言われた。
> She said "Great" to *ME* (although she should've said it to someone else).
> <sub>(Of course the same sentence can also mean "Someone was told 'Great' by me".)</sub>