# Does indirect passive allow for the を in "四方を海に囲まれる"

Tags: particle-に, particle-が, particle-を, passive-voice, によって-passives

My textbook has this example:

> 四方を海に囲まれる。

Is it the *indirect passive* that allows for the **を** direct object marker to be used in that passive voice example?

This sentence matches my understanding of passive voice grammar:

> 四方が海に囲まれる。

Is it also correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My textbook has this example:
>   四方を海に囲まれる。
>   Is it the indirect passive that allows for the を direct object marker to be used in that passive voice example?

The answer is no. It is the **direct passive voice**. The reason will be explained below.

In Japanese, the  passive voice takes human beings (or something **which can feel emotions** as the de-facto subject (before に)), as explained **[here](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%97%E5%8B%95%E6%85%8B)**,

> また直接受身では、「誰々に」を「誰々によって」と言い換えることができるが、迷惑の受身では一般にこの言い換えはできない。

which translates to:

> Moreover, in the case of the *direct passive*, 「誰々に」 can be reworded as
>   「誰々によって」, but, in the case of the *suffering passive*, **such a rewording is not possible**.

Your sentence

> 四方を海に囲まれる。

can be rephrased as

> 四方を海によって（より）囲まれる (I personally think より is more common.)

Now, let's take a look at **[here](http://www.tomojuku.com/blog/passive/passive-4/)** for a full definition of the Japanese direct passive voice.

The **definition of Japanese direct passive voice** is

> ①対応する能動態がある
>   ②迷惑の意味はない
>   （受身文に迷惑の意味があるかどうかは、動詞自体の意味による）
>   ③英語にある

which translates to:

> 1. There is an equivalent phrase that use active voice.
> 2. The sentence does not hint that you may experience an unpleasant moment.
>      (You have to rely on the verb to tell whether the passive voice implies "suffering".)
> 3. It can be translated in English.

You can see that your sentence matches these 3 conditions:

> 1. 四方を海に囲まれる。--> 海が四方を囲む
> 2. No suffering at all is implied. How 四方 would suffer???
> 3. An English translation could be: "The sea encircles all directions".

While Japanese passive voice takes the de-facto subject (why I say de-facto is because when it is converted to active voice, it stands as the subject, in your case: 海), **generally human beings or something which has emotions**, your sentence is a case of **[非情の受身](http://www.tomojuku.com/blog/passive/passive-7/)** (passive voice whose subject is emotionless).

Regarding the explanation of 非情の受身 provided by the link,

> 主語になる物・事には、感情がないので、
>   非情の受身は、多くは客観的な意味を表します。
>   そこで、ニュース、新聞、本で多用されます。
>
> The thing or phenomenon which stands as the subject does not have any kind of emotion, thus, this passive voice is mainly used when one wants to be objective. It is used a lot in news, newspapers or books.

Your sentence seems to describe from an objective point of view.

Thank you. Have a nice day.

Comment: In my humble opinion, 迷惑 shows "trouble" or "annoyance" ("suffering" may be hinted but it's not the general meaning of it). /​/ 迷惑の意味はない  -- The sentence infers some kind of "suffering". I think you've forgotten the negation in your translation. /​/ Your translation of "多くは客観的な意味を表します" seems clunky 客観的 means objective (the writer doesn't tell his/her mind) not narrative (which is more about relating events the point of view used when relating events could be objective as well as subjective). /​/ Besides that, I like your post and your use of references.

Comment: メインは一番初めのウィキの>>間接受身は間接的に影響（ふつうは主語から見て悪影響）を被るものを主語に立てる表現であり、通常、主語は人間である。さらに「迷惑（被害）の受身」、および「持主（所有）受身」などと呼ばれるものに分けられる。が理由です。

Comment: 後直接受動の説明>>元の動作の主語（動作主）を表示するには「に」を用いるのが一般的だが、事物の属性を説明する場合などは「によって」が用いられる。また元の主語からの物の移動（授受）を表す場合は「から」を用いることができる。この場合の文章は四方という（土地？）が海に囲まれている属性と考えられるからです。四方が海により囲まれている。一致します。

Comment: 後英語と同じ性格なら英語も言い換え可能でしょう。人の例ですが,He was hit by the teacher --> The teacher hit him. それで物が事実上の主語なので所謂一般的な事柄を表す無情になるんでしょう。

Comment: 「日本は、四方**を**海に囲まれている。」の能動態は何ですか？ ( 「(日本の)四方**が**海に囲まれている」の能動態を聞いているのではありません)

Comment: これが参考になるのでは無いかと[link](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/7637418.html)花子は　太郎の　顔を　ひっぱたいた。
　→　太郎の顔が　花子に　ひっぱたかれた。（直接受動） 故に**海が日本の四方を囲んでいる**になるのでしょうか？　この場合の構造は間違いならBroccoli氏が訂正してくれそうなんですが,ここ[link](http://choidebu.com/bunpou/ukemi.htm)から推察するにページ下半分当たりの**どちらの目的語も主語に出来るパターン**では無いかと。例として言い換えの能動態➀,海が日本の四方を囲む。②海が日本を四方に囲む。とにかく**日本は、四方を海に囲まれている。**,は**より**をいれても何らの違和感も無くかつ迷惑文に相当しない為直接受身で有ると判断しました。

Comment: 後この場合,「持ち主の受身」は意味が解りませぬ…。

Comment: １点目：「 **海が日本の四方を囲んでいる**になるのでしょうか？」>> いいえ、それは「日本の四方が海に囲まれている」の能動です。「日本は、四方を海に囲まれている。」の能動ではありません。２点目：「ページ下半分当たりのどちらの目的語も主語に出来るパターンでは無いかと。例として言い‌​換えの能動態➀,海が日本の四方を囲む。②海が日本を四方に囲む。」>> いいえ。そのページは「一つの能動態を**二つの受動態**に書き換え可能」（「私は父にバットを与えられました。」と「バットは父によって私に与えられました。」）と言っています。あなたの例文「➀,海が日本の四方を囲む。②海が日本を四方に囲む。」は、「二つの能動態」です。

Comment: そうです。chocoさんが間接受動と仰るのならお答えで頂けませんか？宜しく御願い致します。後**１点目：「 海が日本の四方を囲んでいるになるのでしょうか？」>> いいえ、それは「日本の四方が海に囲まれている」の能動です。**,これ，言い切るのは直観的に違和感を湧きます。目的語が２つないし受動態における間接目的語？相当が有る場合能動態では別の言い方に（日本語では）助詞が変わるのでは無いかと。それと持ち主の受身と仰っておられますが事実上の主語であるモノの場合の持ち主の受身の意味が解りません。兎に角,アンサーで宜しく御願い致します。(m_m)

Comment: ２つの能動態にならざるを得ないのは（日本は）と入れると間接文で言う主語相当,能動文で言う目的語（間接目的語含む）が２つになるからです。

Answer (score 7):

(Here I'm trying to show why 四方**を**海に囲まれる is not direct passive. Please see this as an appendix to broccoliforest's answer and reply to [KentaroTomono's comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27504/does-indirect-passive-allow-for-the-%E3%82%92-in-%E5%9B%9B%E6%96%B9%E3%82%92%E6%B5%B7%E3%81%AB%E5%9B%B2%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B#comment58182_27566).)

---

First, OP's second sentence 四方**が**海に囲まれる is direct passive.

Wikipedia defines「直接受身は、能動文における直接目的語または間接目的語を主語にするものである。」([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%97%E5%8B%95%E6%85%8B#.E7.9B.B4.E6.8E.A5.E5.8F.97.E8.BA.AB)).  Following this definition, a direct passive sentence is formed this way:

The active sentence 海が四方を囲む has a direct object, "四方を".
Use the 四方 as the subject in the direct passive sentence.
You get 四方**が**海に囲まれる。

Therefore, 四方**が**海に囲まれる is direct passive.

---

Now, [this page](http://www.tomojuku.com/blog/passive/passive-4/) says the possessor passive is something like this:

> (1)私は　田中さんに　パソコン**を**　こわされた。← possessor passive
>   cf: (2)私のパソコンが　田中さんに　こわされた。← direct passive
>   ＃2 has a corresponding active voice phrase: 田中さんが  私のパソコンを  こわした。
>   ＃1 doesn't have a corresponding active voice phrase.

The phrases in question can be analysed in the same way:

> (1)島は　海に　四方**を**　囲まれる。 ← possessor passive
>   cf: (2)島の四方が　海に　囲まれる。 ← direct passive
>   ＃2 has a corresponding active phrase: 海が島の四方を囲む。
>   ＃1 doesn't have a corresponding active phrase.

This shows that 四方**を**海に囲まれる is possessor passive, not direct passive.

---

As for the quote from Wikipedia:

> また直接受身では、「誰々に」を「誰々によって」と言い換えることができるが、**迷惑の受身**では一般にこの言い換えはできない。([source](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%97%E5%8B%95%E6%85%8B#.E8.BF.B7.E6.83.91.E3.81.AE.E5.8F.97.E8.BA.AB))

It says **迷惑の受身**ではこの言い換えはできない(the **suffering passive** can't take によって), not **持主の受身**ではこの言い換えはできない(the **possessor passive** can't take によって).  For example, 私は家族を日本兵**に**殺された, which is possessor passive not direct passive, can be rephrased as 私は家族を日本兵**によって**殺された. So you can't conclude that 四方**を**海に囲まれる is direct passive just because you can rephrase it as 四方を海**によって**囲まれる.

---

The conditions of the Japanese direct passive voice are:

> ①対応する能動態がある
>   ②迷惑の意味はない
>   ③英語にある
>   ([source](http://www.tomojuku.com/blog/passive/passive-4/))

First, does 四方**が**海に囲まれる meet these conditions?

> ①It has a corresponding active phrase.
>   →Yes. 海が四方を囲む.
>   海が**四方を**(object)囲む。→ **四方が**(subject)海に囲まれる。
>   ②It doesn't have a meaning of suffering.
>   →No. The subject 四方 doesn't suffer from being surrounded by the sea.
>   ③There is an equivalent passive phrase in English.
>   →Yes. "The four sides are surrounded by the sea."
>   (Not "The sea encircles all directions", which is active voice.)

It meets all these conditions. Therefore, 四方**が**海に囲まれる is direct passive.

Now, does 四方**を**海に囲まれる meet these conditions, too?

> ①It has a corresponding active voice phrase.
>   →No, it has no corresponding active voice phrase.
>   ②It doesn't have a meaning of suffering.
>   →No. In 島は四方**を**海に囲まれている, for example, the island doesn't necessarily suffer from being surrounded by the sea.
>   ③There is an equivalent passive phrase in English.
>   →No, there is no equivalent passive phrase in English.

It doesn't meet ① and ③. Therefore, 四方**を**海に囲まれる is not direct passive.

Is 四方**を**海に囲まれる possessor passive, then? Here's the conditions of the possessor passive:

> ①対応する能動文がない。
>   ②動詞によっては必ずしも迷惑を表さない。
>   ([source](http://www.tomojuku.com/blog/passive/passive-4/))

Does 四方**を**海に囲まれる meet these conditions?

> ①It doesn't have a corresponding active voice phrase.
>   → No, it has no corresponding active phrase.
>   ②It doesn't necessarily indicate suffering, depending on the verb used.
>   → No. In 島は四方**を**海に囲まれる, for example, the island doesn't necessarily suffer from being surrounded by the sea.

It meets both of these conditions, so 四方**を**海に囲まれる is possessor passive, and not direct passive.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Your question actually contains multiple topics.

1. Is 四方を海に囲まれる an indirect passive sentence?
2. Does this type of passive allow for the を?
3. Is 四方が海に囲まれる correct as well?

**Spoiler**: 1.—Maybe, 2.—Yes, 3.—Yes

---

**Is 四方を海に囲まれる an indirect passive sentence?**

Well, it depends. Japanese passive usages can be categorized into three types.

1. **Direct passive**: *you** are affected by *something* doing *something* to *you* (= English passive)
2. **"Possessor" passive**: *you* are affected by *something* doing *something* to *something you own*
3. **"Third party" passive**: *you* are affected by *something* doing *something* (towards *elsewhere*)

*<sub>*you* means the subject of the sentence here</sub>

四方を海に囲まれる "it is surrounded by sea in all directions" falls under #2. It's clear because the word 四方 "all directions" indicates relative position from the reference point, so it has to be "all directions *of somewhere*". Thus, the sentence requires an unpronounced subject as the "owner" of 四方.

What makes your question difficult is, some people call #3 "indirect passive" while others call #2 and #3 "indirect passive". So if you ask people whether it is an "indirect passive", you might get different opinions. But it couldn't be #1 or #3.

**Does this type of passive allow for the を?**

Yes, in fact, it has to. By definition (see above), #2 passives requires an object other than *you* (i.e. the subject of the sentence) and the object remains in を-case. Meanwhile, the type #3 doesn't have to, because the action doesn't have to be transitive. A typical example of that is `雨に降られた` (lit. "I was rained") "I got caught in the rain", which describes that it was just raining irrespective of me, and the unfortunate me happened to be there too.

**Is 四方が海に囲まれる correct as well?**

Yes, grammatically it's an ordinary #1 passive. And in this case, Japanese grammar is so evil that this sentence has the same meaning as 四方**を**海に囲まれる. But it's only because 四方 request for an "owner" (as said above) and Japanese can utilize the [double nominative construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9788/7810) to fulfill it. Of course, you can't expect to paraphrase all these kind of passives using direct passive, especially when the subject is human: if you'd say `兄が彼に殺された` I'd assume you were talking about your brother, but `兄を彼に殺された` I'd assume the subject would be you, who had the experience that whose brother was killed by him.

Comment: So the "owner" is Japan.........which is not a person......could you kindly define the difference of "owning" and the "properties" as a professional? ( Not with sarcasm )

Comment: No, I shouldn't have said **Japan**, in your case, **it.** While denoting the properties of it falls into the direct passive, whereas the possessive case falls into the indirect, where would you **draw the line** between the **properties** of the subject ( here, the sea might sound the **properties** as well, well, yes, considering, for example, EEZ ( Exclusive Economic Zone ), it will probably fall into the **possession**. Can you please tell me the **line**, kindly.

Comment: And I would like to ask one more thing. You are saying **Direct passive -- YOU are affected by something doing something to YOU**. In this case, are you presupposing 有情's case? In your definition, who are **you** here?? Since I thought we should distinguish between if one falls into direct or indirect **and** if the speech has the emotion or is motionless, in my answer I distinguished so, but I think asserting such is a bit risky here may be??

Comment: @KentaroTomono The "[possession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_%28linguistics%29)" as a linguistic jargon is quite hard to explain briefly in plain language. In short, you can say it's a relation connected by _'s_ or _of_. Maybe I should consider the wording.

Comment: @KentaroTomono No, I'm not presupposing only animate things. I think animacy itself is not required to be taken into account in this question, though there's certainly differences in animate- and inanimate-subject passives. Anyway, _you_ is a bit of underexplanation on second thought, thank you for pointing it.

Comment: Kindly, I would like to know especially about モノ’s case, because the Japanese passive generally takes human beings ( or something that has the emotion ) as the --de facto-- subject, it is not hard to me....( but for the J-learner's sake...well, kindly consider appropriately ). Thank you **personally** in advance. (m_m)

Comment: @KentaroTomono I think your answer has already given a great overview on how 非情の受身 works in Japanese. Answers can be complementary for each other, although I don't much agree with you that this usage is a _direct passive_ (at least, syntactically).

Comment: Yes, please. The OP can switch the best answer. But my pure interest is... **I would like to know why this is not the direct passive**.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the indirect passive (aka "suffering passive") allows for を to mark the object of a transitive verb.

There are, in general, three basic structures to create a passive in Japanese:

1. [subject] が [agent] に [transitive verb]
2. [subject] が [agent] に [object] を [transitive verb]
3. [subject] が [agent] に [intransitive verb]

Number 1 is the regular passive that also corresponds to English passive. Numbers 2 and 3 are the indirect passive forms that you are referring to, indicating that misfortune occurred to the subject because the agent did the said verb.

The example your textbook gave has structure 2. Because of the を, we know it is indirect passive. The subject has been removed, but I will assume it is the speaker. The sentence can be translated as:

> 四方を海に囲まれる。
>   Every direction is surrounded by the sea (and that is unfortunate [for me]).

The speaker may be stuck on an island.

Now, replacing the を with が moves it to the first structure. Now the whole "misfortune" part is no longer implied.

> 四方が海に囲まれる。
>   Every direction is surrounded by the sea.

Comment: I would like to write the reason for downvoting.

Comment: @KentaroTomono I was not aware that によって changed the passive in that way. I learned a lot from your post. But is this interpretation still possible, or should I delete my answer?

Comment: I don't know. You see we are the native speakers, so honestly speaking, **if we talk each other about this**, I would say **sooo.....?**. But since we are answering to J-learners, I always cite some source which I learned at philosophy site ( one of my favorites ).....kindly see about によって to  the source **after all I am also learning**................................