# Passive voice and complex or connecting sentence

Tags: usage, particles, passive-voice

Imagine a situation where you've been informed by Mr. Rentarou that on Wednesday you will have an interview with Ms. Suzuki. Then, you've decided to confirm the information directly to Ms. Suzuki.

I've come up with 2 sentences

> 1. 廉太郎さんに伝えられましたが、水曜日には面談がありますね?
> 2. 廉太郎さんに水曜日には面談があると伝えられましたが。

I learned that in Japanese, they prefer using a passive voice "I have been told by Mr. Rentarou ~" rather than "Mr. Rentarou told me ~". In this situation is the passive voice preferred?

Lastly, I am confused that sometimes が or けど doesn't always translate as "but", rather it implies something else depending on the context. This is why the first sentence "I've been told by Mr. Rentarou, **but** on Wednesday I will have an interview (with you)," sounds weird to me. Is my correction (the second sentence) better?

Please fix if I used the wrong vocabulary for the phrases.

Answer (score 1):

> > 1. 廉太郎さんに伝えられましたが、水曜日には面談があります**よ**ね?
> > 2. 廉太郎さんに水曜日には面談があると伝えられましたが。
>
> they prefer using a passive voice

It's not that we prefer passive voice but the speaker being the subject of the sentence rather than the third party. ([Animacy hierarchy](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/21218/%E3%81%AF-%E3%81%8C-and-%E3%82%92-with-the-passive-form/21261#21261)) Anyway, it's true that those example sentences are natural in this regard.

> Is my correction (the second sentence) better?

Either will do. If anything, you might mind that the second one is not a complete sentence, though that's not uncommon at all, after all.