# "を奪{うば}われた" used incorrectly instead of "が奪{うば}われた"? (Bleach)

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-が, particle-を, passive-voice

In Bleach Sennen Kessen-hen (S01,E04), (slight spoilers) captains have an ability called Bankai. They thought that the enemy could seal this ability. But as KB realizes, the enemy actually steals this ability.
The actual dialogue being "Chigau, fuuin de ha nai. Bankai wo...ubawareta!"

clip: https://i.imgur.com/x6dazu6.mp4

But this seems...wrong grammatically? Shouldn't it be "Bankai ga ubawareta" (my bankai was stolen), or else "Bankai wo ubatta" (they stole my bankai)?

Or is it the case that KB is saying two seperate phrases? (i.e. "bankai wo...", and then, after a pause, "ubawareta...").

Edit: in the following scene, someone explicitly says "bankai wo ubawareta" (with no ambiguous pause), so maybe my understanding of japanese grammar is wrong? Can "を" naturally be used with the passive voice like this? Or is this some kind of special case? @.@ As an example, the sentence "the pudding was eaten by Hanako" would always be "プリン(が/は)花子に食べられた", it would never have an "を" particle, right? @.@

Comment: This is a typical example of "indirect passive". You can say 花子にプリンを食べられた "I had my pudding eaten by Hanako".

Comment: @naruto thanks! https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/11026/35659 answers it perfectly! I wasn't exactly aware of this grammar form till now.